End of Mankind movie
I remember when I was a little boy there was a movie about an alien invasion. The end of the movie was a scene with a newsreader and during his words the broadcast ends in a snowy screen and a high monotone beep, as if the aliens annihilated all mankind. In all lists of famous movies I couldn't find any movie ending like this.
I think it's a movie between '90 and '00..

Interesting one, but can you add any more details? Seems a bit sparse which would make it difficult to track.

I think I know what you're looking for, but I'm going to work now, please add as much detail as you can and I will verify tonight.

I can't add any detail. The monotone beep was the thing which remains in my memory. It's annoying: Except for 'The Ring', how hard can it be to find out which movie had also white noise in it's ending..

I think you're looking for Without Warning (1994)

While there wasn't much detail to go on I was able to verify the ending using YouTube - This is a link to the full movie. 
It's a CBS TV-movie which explains why you have had difficulty finding it.
The ending is exactly as you describe and the movie is indeed about visitors from another planet. Believing, or atleast, having been told that it's an asteroid, the world unites in shooting nukes at them and they retaliate in full force thereby dooming mankind.
The ending is truly excellent and it's an overall great watch that I would recommend to anyone. 

"I can't even find it on IMDb" Er, look at the bottom of that Wiki link you put up... ;)

huh, strange. When I searched for it another movie and no other results came up. I didn't exactly read the entire wiki :) thanks :)

How great this is.. Been searching for it for a looooong time!! Thanks for the effort!!
